# Can I label knitr code chunks and outputs and add captions to them?

Tags: r, latex, label, caption, knitr

Is it possible to add labels and references to knitr output other than figures and tables. 
I know I can use `xtable` respectively `print.xtable` to set captions for tables and place them like I would like to. A similar thing can be done to figures. But is it possible to label and caption some output that was generated 
simply by echoing some R code? So that I could write something like this in my text: `code chunk \ref{mychunk} shows how to do XYZ`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is possible. See [example 074](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/074-example-environment.Rnw) on how to define an environment for R chunks so that you can make use of cross references. To completely understand it, you may need to read the documentation of [chunk hooks](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks).

Comment: Thx for helping out for the second time within the last 24 hrs. For me  it might be the other way around: read too much documentation and less examples. Just learned they existed despite using knitr and several of its advanced options for a while. Maybe you should link from the demos to the examples on github. However, others maybe better finding them, thx man!

Comment: I have been working on a knitr book (which discussed this feature in detail), so there was lower priority on the website. You are absolutely right that I should have a link in the demo page, although I already have one in the homepage.

Comment: a knitr book! that's absolutely awesome. That's most definitely the right excuse for that missing link. I will tell everybody and their grandmothers when that book is out.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted additional text in the caption after the head, so used this in the preamble for customizing my code chunk captions using amsthm:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{rexample}
    {3pt}%Space above
    {3pt}% Space below
    {}%Body font
    {}%Indent amount
    {\bfseries}%Theorem head font
    {:}%Punctuation after theorem head
    {.5em}%Space after theorem head
    {}%Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning `normal')
\theoremstyle{rexample}
\newtheorem{rexample}{Code chunk}
```

Following the example, I used knit_hooks with options$comment:

```
knit_hooks$set(rexample = function(before, options, envir) {
  if (before) sprintf('\\begin{rexample}%s\\label{%s}\\hfill{}', options$comment, options$label) else '\\end{rexample}'
})
```

And in the chunk definition, the comment is passed to form the label:

```
<<setup, echo=TRUE, tidy=FALSE, eval=FALSE, rexample=TRUE, comment='Setups for some management functions and database connections'>>=
```

Which gives me a nice caption:

http://gis.washington.edu/phurvitz/knitr/rexample_theorem_caption.png

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but try and give this site a shot:
http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/reference/

Don't be irritated by the first sentence talking about Sweave chunks, it's totally focused on knitr chunks.

Cheers ...